# Getting errors when running app on iPhone 5 and 4. Runs fine on 6

Tags: ios, swift, crash

So here's the deal. I'm getting the following error when running my app on anything below iPhone 6. It works fine on 6+. 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.' I marked where below near the bottom.

Very odd that this runs fine on 6 and 6+ but crashes on anything else. Can someone explain why this is?

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, LYRQueryControllerDelegate {

var QueryController: LYRQueryController!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func queryControllerDidChangeContent(queryController: LYRQueryController!) {
    updateMessageCount()
}

func updateMessageCount()
{

    setUpQuery()
    let count = self.QueryController.count()
    if count == 0
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
       (self.tabBar.items!.last as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = nil
    }
    else
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = Int(count)
        (self.tabBar.items!.last as! UITabBarItem).badgeValue = "\(count)"

    }
}


func setUpQuery() {
    if QueryController == nil {
        let layerClient = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).layerClient
        var unreadMessages :Int = 0

        var Query = LYRQuery(queryableClass: LYRMessage.self)

        // Messages must be unread
        var unreadPredicate = LYRPredicate(property: "isUnread", predicateOperator: LYRPredicateOperator.IsEqualTo, value: true)
        // Messages must not be sent by the authenticated user
//            var userPredicate = LYRPredicate(property: "sender.userID", predicateOperator: LYRPredicateOperator.IsNotEqualTo, value: layerClient.authenticatedUserID)

        Query.predicate = LYRCompoundPredicate(type: LYRCompoundPredicateType.And, subpredicates: [unreadPredicate])


        self.QueryController = layerClient.queryControllerWithQuery(Query)
//this line right under is causing the crash.
        QueryController.delegate = self
        QueryController.execute(nil)

    }
}

}
```

abstract Creates and returns a new query controller with the given query.
     @param query The query to create a controller with.
     @return A newly created query controller.
     */
    - (LYRQueryController *)queryControllerWithQuery:(LYRQuery *)query;

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and single-stepping to determine why `layerClient.queryControllerWithQuery(Query)` is returning nil?  Also, by convention  `QueryController` should be `queryController`

Comment: @Paulw11 I did, but again nothing I can see. I could be missing something however.

Comment: So, did that method return nil or did it return a valid object and you still get a crash?  Are you using beta XCode/Swift? Can you show the code for that method?

Comment: @Paulw11 it returned nil. Printing description of self.QueryController:
(LYRQueryController!) QueryController = nil.  The above code is all that exists for that class. To make matters even weirder. I just pushed this out on testflight and I had someone with an iPhone 5 test it and it worked fine.

Comment: So, if it returned nil, why did it return nil?  I mean the source code for `queryControllerWithQuery`

Comment: @Paulw11 I have absolutely no idea. The source code for that is fairly long, but I'll paste in the jist in an edit. It's throwing me for a loop again because of the selective nature of the error.

Comment: When I was referring to stepping through in the debugger, I mean to step *into* this method and see where it returns nil